# How can the Corda node be extended to work with databases other than H2?

Tags: corda

I have run Corda with PostgreSQL. How can Corda be extended to work with other databases? Is it enough to add the database driver as a Gradle dependency and try connecting to other databases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Corda uses Hibernate 5.x with HikariCP JDBC connection pool.

All queries are generated by Hibernate,  expect one query from the `finance` module (`CashSelection` uses a JDBC `PreparedStatement` with SQL constructs specific to each database vendor).

**Configuring the database**

At runtime, a node looks up the JDBC settings in its `node.conf` file. By default, it connects to the embedded H2 server (see the file `/node/src/main/resources/reference.conf` in the Corda source code).

To use Corda with other databases(*) or connect with non-default settings, the `node.conf` file needs to set the node's data source properties:

```
dataSourceProperties = {
    dataSourceClassName = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
    dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://[HOST]:[PORT]/postgres"
    dataSource.user = [USER]
    dataSource.password = [PASSWORD]
}
database = {
    transactionIsolationLevel = READ_COMMITTED
}
jarDirs = [PATH_TO_JDBC_DRIVER_DIR]
```

where `dataSourceProperties` are the typical JDBC settings, the `database` entry contains Hibernate specific settings, and `jarDirs` is a list of paths to the directories containing the driver (e.g. `jarDirs = ['/Library/postgres-lib']`).

**Configuring the database in deployNodes**

You can avoid configuring the database settings manually by passing the settings in `deployNodes`. For example:

```
node {
    name "O=Bank C,L=Tokyo,C=JP"
    p2pPort 10010
    webPort 10011
    rpcSettings {
        address("localhost:10036")
        adminAddress("localhost:10037")
    }
    cordapps = ["$project.group:finance:$corda_release_version"]
    rpcUsers = ext.rpcUsers
    extraConfig = [
        ‘dataSourceProperties.dataSource.url’ : ‘jdbc:postgresql://localhost:32774/postgres’,
        ‘dataSourceProperties.dataSourceClassName’ : ‘org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource’,
        ‘dataSourceProperties.dataSource.user’ : ‘postgres’,
        ‘dataSourceProperties.dataSource.password’ : ‘postgres’,
        ‘jarDirs’ : [ ‘/Library/Java/postgres’ ]
    ]
}
```

**Adding the driver**

Once these settings have been added, the JDBC driver needs to be added to the location specified in `extraConfig.jarDirs` after the node has been deployed.

The alternative is to add the JDBC driver dependency in `node/build.gradle` (as it is done for PostgreSQL). Whenever a node is compiled/built, it will contain the driver out-of-the-box.

(*) Corda Open Source is shipped with the H2 file database, and has experimental support for Postgres and Sql Server. Corda Enterprise has wider tested support for other databases including Sql Server, AzureSQL, Postgres, and Oracle databases. Despite using Hibernate/JDBC, some queries may require modification in order to be compatible across all supported databases. This compatibility is supported by Corda Enterprise.

Comment: Removed reference to `schema` as per simon_sz's correction.

Comment: This works.  Any suggestion though on bringing the username/password in via a gradle.properties file or similar.  Param substitution is running into troubles when running deployNodes. > bug in method caller: not valid to create ConfigValue from: [PASSWORD_VALUE]

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Joel's answer: 
the option `schema = [SCHEMA]` is not available in Corda Open Source, some drivers allow to set up the current schema in JDBC URL string.
For Corda 3.X dataSourceProperties keys containing `.` should be wrapped in double quotes to properly override the default settings (described in https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/4037) e.g.

```
dataSourceProperties = {
    "dataSource.url" = "jdbc:postgresql://[HOST]:[PORT]/postgres"
    ...
```

or in deployNodes:

```
extraConfig = [
               'dataSourceProperties': [
                          '"dataSource.url"': 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres',
                          ...
```