# Error when add dataSourceProperties into "deployNodes"

Tags: corda

I want to set up a Corda Node with Oracle 11g database in Corda 3.1 Enterprise Version:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordapp'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation'
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
jar.baseName = "cordapp-example"

task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
directory "./build/nodes"
node {
    name "O=Notary Pool,L=Sao Paolo,C=BR"
    notary = [validating : false]
    p2pPort 10002
    rpcSettings {
        address("localhost:10003")
        adminAddress("localhost:10043")
    }
    webPort 10004
    cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
    rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
}
node {
    name "O=First Bank of London,L=London,C=GB"
    p2pPort 10005
    rpcSettings {
        address("localhost:10006")
        adminAddress("localhost:10046")
    }
    webPort 10007
    cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
    rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    dataSourceProperties {
        dataSourceClassName = "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
        dataSource.url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:db11g2"
        dataSource.user = "sys"
        dataSource.password = "98765"
    }
    database = {
        transactionIsolationLevel = READ_COMMITTED
        schema = "db11g2"
    }

}
}
```

There is a error when I deploy this task:

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * Where:
 Build file 'D:\WorkPlaceCorda\TestDatabase\cordapp-example\kotlin-source\build.gradle' line: 94

 * What went wrong:
 A problem occurred evaluating project ':kotlin-source'.
 Could not find method dataSourceProperties() for arguments [build_4c7s0yjnncjhr0s832fhma3b4$_run_closure6$_closure16$_closure21@45dad5d1] on object of type net.corda.plugins.Node.
```

So, How to config parameter "dataSourceProperties" to connect this Node to Oracle database?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the error describes gradle build failure. So it must be related to gradle file syntax. Just wondering if it is because of the missing equal to sign (**=**), after dataSourceProperties tag in your gradle file?

Also note that there is a basic set of defaults loaded from the built in resource file 
*/node/src/main/resources/reference.conf* of the :node gradle module. The dataSourceProperties tag is present in the default set of reference configuration. We should be using exactly same set of keys (including the double quotes), while overriding the default tag.

Please check by updating the build.gradle file as follows:

```
dataSourceProperties = {
    dataSourceClassName = "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    "dataSource.url" = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:db11g2"
    "dataSource.user" = "sys"
    "dataSource.password" = "98765"
}
```

Comment: where should these statements be inserted in the gradle build file ?

Answer (score 1):

@Henry, in order to accomplish what you want to do in the `deployNodes` task, you have to use an entry named `extraConfig`, like this:

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
...
  node {
  ...
     extraConfig = [
       "dataSourceProperties.dataSourceClassName"  = "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource",
       "dataSourceProperties.dataSource.url"       = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:db11g2",
       "dataSourceProperties.dataSource.user"      = "sys",
       "dataSourceProperties.dataSource.password"  = "98765",
       "database.transactionIsolationLevel"        = "READ_COMMITED",
       "database.schema"                           = "YOUR_DB_SCHEMA",
       "database.runMigration"                     = "true"
    ]
  ...
  }
```

You can use `dataSourceProperties.{}` directly if you are modifying some `node.conf` file.

The whole process is detailed here: [Corda with Databases other than H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232016/how-can-the-corda-node-be-extended-to-work-with-databases-other-than-h2)

[corda](/questions/tagged/corda)