# using global properties to configure db

Tags: corda

I followed the link [How can the Corda node be extended to work with databases other than H2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232016/how-can-the-corda-node-be-extended-to-work-with-databases-other-than-h2/52744565#52744565) to connect to pgdb. Is there a way to define global config and reuse, for example maintain global config for "dataSource.user", "dataSource.password", dataSourceClassName and refer them in gradle task deployNodes..? Also, is there a way to encrypt "dataSource.password" and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Gradle property to provide a global constant that you can use in your Gradle build scripts. For example, suppose you wanted to set the node's RPC password using a constant. You would:

1. Add a property to the `gradle.properties` file (e.g. `rpc_password=my_test_password`)
2. Use this property inside `deployNodes`. For example:

   ```
   task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
       directory "./build/nodes"
       node {
           ...
           rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": rpc_password, "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

There is no way to encrypt the database password currently. Only RPC credentials can be encrypted.