# How to integrate PostgreSQL with Corda 3.0 or with Corda 4.0?

Tags: postgresql, corda

I tried to configure PostgreSQL as node's database in Corda 3.0 and in Corda 4.0. 
I have added following things in build.gradle file. (Testdb1 is Database name. I have tried with postgres also)

```
node{
...
    // this part i have added
    extraConfig = [
        jarDirs: ['path'],
            'dataSourceProperties': [
                    'dataSourceClassName': 'org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource',
                    '"dataSource.url"'     : 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/Testdb1',
                    '"dataSource.user"'    : 'postgres',
                    '"dataSource.password"': 'admin@123'
            ],
            'database': [
                    'transactionIsolationLevel': 'READ_COMMITTED'
            ]
    ]
    // till here
}
```

this part in reference.conf file

```
dataSourceProperties = {
    dataSourceClassName = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
    dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/Testdb1"
    dataSource.user = postgres
    dataSource.password = "admin@123"
}
database = {
    transactionIsolationLevel = "READ_COMMITTED"
}
jarDirs = ["path"]
```

I got the follwing Error while deploying the nodes:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
            * What went wrong:
            Execution failed for task ':java-source:deployNodes'.
```

In node-info-gen.log file it showed the CAPSULE EXCEPTION. Then I updated my JDK to 8u191 but still got the same error.

I have go-through the followings to get the things done. One can get reference from here.
https://docs.corda.net/node-database.html ,
https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/4037 ,
[How can the Corda node be extended to work with databases other than H2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232016/how-can-the-corda-node-be-extended-to-work-with-databases-other-than-h2/52744565#52744565)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those properties in node.conf in each of your corda nodes. After you do "deployNodes"

After you add these properties in node.conf file ,  just run the corda jar . It will automatically start . But before that you need to create the tables (The migration to other DBs is already provided in corda documentation)

Answer (score 0):

I have added following things in **.conf** file of each node and one **referene.conf** file. I have given all the privileges for the user postgres which are mentioned in corda documentation.
https://docs.corda.r3.com/node-database.html

(previously I used **postgresql-42.2.5.jar** file but that didn't work so I used one downgrade version of it **postgresql-42.1.4.jar**.
one can download jar files from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html )

After deployed Nodes successfully add following things:

```
dataSourceProperties = {
    dataSourceClassName = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
    dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/Testdb1"
    dataSource.user = postgres
    dataSource.password = "admin@123"
}
database = {
    transactionIsolationLevel = "READ_COMMITTED"
}
jarDirs = ["path"]
```

(path = jar file's location) after adding this configuration run file called **runnodes.bat**