# How can i configure a database in the node.conf file using Corda RPC?

Tags: blockchain, rpc, corda

I am using Corda version 4 community edition and I am trying to use a database like MySQL instead of the traditional H2 database. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you share your `node.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

Community (or Opensource) version only tested with H2, Postgres and SQLServer. If you want to use mySql you've to upgrade to Enterprise version.

Hope this help

Comment: Yes, but we can also integrate an external database in community addition by changing the config files after creating the build and providing the JDBC url however, it is not allowing to give the rpc connection properties.

Comment: Did you config rpc and db like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232016/how-can-the-corda-node-be-extended-to-work-with-databases-other-than-h2

Comment: Thanks for the link, it explains everything.